# trimming white space at end of lines javascript

Tags: javascript, regex, minify, jsmin

I am running a js file through a minifier which is leaving line breaks at unexplained positions.

For example currently I have the following code:

```
var example = "var name = 'john';
               function sayName () {
                 alert('hi');
               }
               var person = {
                 name: 'peter',
                 sayName: function() {
                    alert('this is my name ' + this.name);
                 }
               }"
```

After it is run through the minifier I get:

```
var name='john';function sayName(){alert('hi');}
var person={name:'peter',sayName:function(){alert('this is my name '+this.name);}}
```

I have tried many regex and `trim()` but cannot figure out how to fix this. Does anyone have an idea of how to remove the white lines at the end of a line?

Comment: Where does the `var example` and that syntax-error string literal come from?

Comment: Still invalid after the edit - you can't have a multiline string.

Comment: apologies, that was a small off sight on my part. I shortened the example for the purpose of the question and forgot the closing `"`

Comment: @vlaz and berg, weird! its in a script.js file and when i check `typeof` I get string. I am running it through an npm module which is reading the file

Comment: Let me clarify - you _can_ have a string with newlines in it, you cannot have a string that starts on one line (`"` open on line 1) and ends in another (closing `"` on another). You can have a string on one line, then end it on the same line and use `+` to join it to the string on the next line. So, you get `"hello\n" + "world"` if you want a string with two lines in it.

Comment: At any rate, `trim()` _on a string_ will only remove starting and ending whitespace, e.g. `"     hello  \n" + "  world  "` will be turned into `"hello  \n" + "  world"` but notice that whitespace in the middle is _not_ affected. Unless you are calling a different `trim()` or something, it won't trim every line.

Comment: @phantom: Are you saying that the string is actually coming from reading a file, but you decided to represent it as `var example = "..."`? If so, please don't do that. Describe *exactly* what you're doing in the question. These shortcuts just waste people's time.

Comment: APOLOGIES ALLl! I will be in trouble here. I had to update the question as there was one step i had 'mis-debugged'. this is in direct reply to @squint also! sorry again

Comment: Which minifier are you using that produces this output, and what exactly is unexpected?

Comment: @Bergi should there be a new line? I thought if i minified the code it should not contain these new lines like if you run it through https://javascript-minifier.com/ it is coming from `jsmin`

Comment: If you're using jsmin, keep your expectations low or just find a better minifier.

Comment: @squint ok, its not considered good?

Comment: Try `.replace(/^\s+|\s+$|[\r\n]+/gm, '')` or explain what output you need.

Comment: There's very little that comes from Crockford that I consider good. You shouldn't need to post-process the output from a minifier in order to improve its result. There are many others that'll do a better job.

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this:

```
var withoutWhitespaceAtLineEnd = example.split(/\n/).map(function(line){
  return line.replace(/\s+$/,'');
}).join("\n");
```

Comment: man, apologies, I updated the question. I will look at the solution but just so you know its worth seeing the update